# How do you download an older version of UiPath Studio?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-api

I have installed UiPath Studio but it is version 21.4 and I need 20.8 to study for the latest UiPath Assiciates Exam.

How do you download an old version of UiPath Studio and stop it from updating automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community edition of UiPath Studio will always force an update to the latest release.

Many developers studying for the [UiPath Associate exam](https://www.rpacertified.com/study-guide-uipath.html) that deals with version 20.8 were surprised to see their local development environment updated to 21.4. All of sudden the tool they were using was not in sync with the tool they were being tested on.

Short of blocking all Internet access to your computer, you can't stop UiPath Studio  CE from upgrading itself. It's just part of the product.

### Stop Automatic UiPath Updates

However, the Enterprise Edition of UiPath Studio allows you to both shut off automatic downloads, and it gives you an option to [download older UiPath versions](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/download-old-UiPath-Studio-specific-version-stop-updates) of the tool. The problem is an enterprise license costs thousands of dollars. For those short on cash, you can opt for the free 60 day trial.

So that's basically the answer. To download and install a specific version of UiPath Studio, you need an enterprise license.

### Community vs Enterprise Editions

Here's a good chart to contrast [UiPath Studio Community vs Enterprise](https://youtu.be/bP_knaHu_uE) editions:

[image: UiPath Studio and Community Compared]

Answer (score 2):

You can't download an old Studio version, sadly. That only works if you are using the Enterprise version. There you can downgrade to the last 5 versions.

Indeed, very poor that they do not let the use decide what to use.